# Query MongoDB using VB.NET - nullable types

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, nullable

The MongoDB C# driver supports queries on Nullable(Of T) according to this Jira ticket:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-483

However, I am having issues getting it working.

```
mycol.AsQueryable.Where(Function(p) p.MyNullableInteger = 3)
```

As instructed, I removed the `.Value` property from the query, however that breaks strict typing, so I had to remove my `Option Strict On` clause. It then compiled successfully however I would ideally like that clause back in.

The PredicateTranslator is throwing an exception as follows:

**Unsupported where clause: (Boolean)(p.MyNullableInteger == (Nullable)3)**

The actual Where clause expression generated by .NET is:

**p => Convert((p.MyNullableInteger == ConvertChecked(3)))**

I am using driver 1.5. My POCO class does register a classmap but the mapping does not reference the property here (it is just setting representation from String to ObjectId for my Id property).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is only a bug in Visual Basic.  It works fine in C#.  I have created a Jira here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-542.

I'm also going to edit your question tags to include VB as opposed to c#.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Yes sorry I actually meant to say "C# driver" originally in my title. Good to know I'm not going mad. My workaround in this case is just to use regular Integers - I could switch to c# I guess too :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get the name changed to the .net driver.  No discrimination here :).  All our other drivers are named after the languages they support, hence the initial reasoning.